# How to get the composer of specific version

Tags: composer-php

When I run

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\nrna> `composer -V`
```

```
Composer version 1.9.0 2019-08-02 20:55:32
```

Now, I want the composer with version 1.6.3

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `self-update` command, specifying the version.

E.g:

```
composer self-update 1.6.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the version when you run the installer with the `--version` flag:

```
php composer-setup.php --version=1.6.3
```

You can use 
you can find more information and installation options in the [download page](https://getcomposer.org/download/) of composer.

Looks like you are using windows, please refer to [manual installation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#manual-installation) for more detailed instructions.

**Step by step instructions:**

1. Download installer file

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
```

2. Check the integrity of the installer (*optional*)

```
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'a5c698ffe4b8e849a443b120cd5ba38043260d5c4023dbf93e1558871f1f07f58274fc6f4c93bcfd858c6bd0775cd8d1') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
```

3. run the installer with the desired options

```
php composer-setup.php --version=1.6.3 --filename=composer.phar
```

4. Check installation

```
php composer.phar --version
```

5. remove installer

```
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Comment: i had that file. Plz provide me the full step for installing that file.

Comment: Yes, I tried. Idownloaded the file with my version and run. ```C:\>php composer-setup.php --filename=composer.phar
Could not open input file: composer-setup.php
```

Comment: have you downloaded the composer-setup.php file as described in the [download page](https://getcomposer.org/download/)?

Comment: @CHARITRASHRESTHA I have added step by step instructions, I hope this is more clear on how to do this.

Comment: Yes, i had download that file. Then what to do?

Comment: I updated my answer with step by step instructions, if you did everything correct you may call composer with the following command `php composer.phar` followed by your command, for example: `php composer.phar install`